# Unique usernames in 2 tables at different levels. Suitable database design?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have a table with suppliers. This table contains, among other things, name, username and password hash.

Sometimes a supplier is just one person, in which case this works fine. But sometimes a supplier is a company and in that case, multiple employees may need to log in. Until now, all supplier employees shared one username/password per supplier. Now I want to give everybody individual credentials.

I already have a table with supplier contacts, so it would be easiest to add 2 columns for username and password hash to that table. However, since I want to keep the option of having usernames and password hashes in the supplier table for one-person suppliers, I can't create a unique index for usernames, because they're spread out over 2 tables.

I could of course enforce the unique usernames in PHP, but I wonder if I'm making a database design mistake. I considered creating a new table 'users' to put all credentials in but somehow it doesn't feel right. Any tips?

Comment: Thanks to all who answered. I decided to follow David Aldridge's advice and let go of provider-level logins. I selected Jo Douglass's answer because it discusses different options in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that both David Aldridge and Ray More have given you potentially suitable design suggestions, but I'd like to answer your question a little more holistically, and with a concentration on your statement that "[you] wonder if [you're] making a database design mistake."

---

**Short version:** Yes, I think you *are* making a design mistake - insisting on putting single-person supplier login details in the Supplier table - and this is causing you to reject both your own alternative ideas, and those suggested by others.

**Long version:** First, think about this conceptually, rather than technically. Who do the login details belong to? In the past, they belonged to the supplier. Now, they belong to the supplier employee.

Earlier in the data modelling process (i.e. before you reach the point of creating a physical model), we talk about attributes rather than columns, and entities rather than tables - so the login details are attributes of a supplier employee entity rather than attributes of a supplier entity. That means when you reach your physical database design, those columns should be in (or associated with) the SupplierContact table.

So why do the logins always belong to the supplier employee rather than the supplier? Think about this scenario:

> You work with a supplier which has a single employee, so you create
>   one set of login details for them. A year later, the supplier's
>   business expands, and the person running it hires an assistant - they
>   also need access, so you need to make another set of login details for
>   the same supplier.

With the model you're suggesting, you'd need to delete the current login details from the Supplier table, and add two sets of details to SupplierContact. Depending on your application design, you might also find yourself needing to close the supplier's original account or forcing a reset of their password - which would be irritating for them.

---

**Alternative situation:** If you have a legitimate reason for having two different types of account - an organisational account for suppliers and an individual account for supplier employees - then it's a different situation. However, you could still achieve both goals of having all accounts in one table while still associating each type of account with the relevant table (i.e. Supplier or SupplierContact).

For example, you could have a table called Account which held the login details. From there, there are several options in order to link that table to either Supplier **or** SupplierContact. I don't want to get into a which option to choose as its an issue that's well-discussed elsewhere (including on SO), and is arguably a matter of taste, but here are some options:

- Include two nullable foreign key columns in Account, one which can hold the SupplierId, and one which can hold the SupplierContactId. Potentially build a constraint to ensure that one of the two is always populated.
- Create two separate tables, SupplierAccount and SupplierContactAccount, with two columns each. The first should have SupplierId and AccountId columns with foreign keys to Supplier and Account, and the second should have SupplierContactId and AccountId columns with foreign keys to SupplierContact and Account. Potentially build constraints to ensure that rows in Account are not being associated with more than one Supplier or SupplierContact.

Please note that I **would not do the above** unless I really had two different types of account. It's added complexity, and should not be done unless it is *needed*; if your only reason for keeping the details associated with Supplier is that you are used to that structure or simply prefer it that way, then don't do it.

---

**Another alternative:** I had another thought on this in the meantime. I'll not go into heaps of detail as you've already accepted this and presumably know enough to move on, but another option would be to use the Party data modelling pattern.

This pattern can be good for dealing with situations where you need to interact in similar ways with both individuals and organisations or groups of people. It's also useful for situations like the one Dennis has mentioned, where you might interact with an individual or organisation in multiple different ways - i.e. a Party might play more than one Role.

[Here's an article](http://www.univdata.com/Portals/9/udm_Publication_Articles_11_05_Models_Patterns.pdf) about this idea here which I found useful when I first ran across it. Len Silverston, who wrote that article, has also published some very helpful data modelling books if you want to get more in-depth. The books work from the more conceptual/abstract level right down to physical database schemas. If you look around online for the party data model pattern I'm sure you can find similar resources online, if this does look useful for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good case for creating a second table.

Consider the following table structures:

```
Suppliers: SupplierId, Name, Address, etc..
SupplierLogins: SupplierLoginId, SupplierId, Username, Password
```

You can use this structure to add a single login, or multiple logins.  Your unique combination could be on the `SupplierId, Username` combination.  IMO, email ids are a great login - it eliminates the need for having to remember a username.

Also, for example, if Joel@Superuser.com changes his job and goes to a different supplier then he becomes Joel@AskDifferent.com, so you don't have to lose the data of all the things under the old login.

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm missing in your answer is a link between the logins and the contacts table.

Answer (score 1):

I would place all logins in the contact table, even for suppliers with a single login. You still need contact information for the supplier's one login, put put all similar information in one table.

Comment: I thought about that, but ideally I would like to keep the option of having usernames and password hashes in the supplier table for one-person suppliers. I agree your suggestion is neater though.

Comment: Well, you can't have the convenience of the same type of data across two tables without the inconvenience of finding it difficult to enforce uniqueness. Having all the logins in a single table is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation and maybe you can take something from it. First you should consider if a supplier really only is a supplier. In many cases a supplier can potentially also be a client. Suddenly your whole situation can become much more complicated with your current setup. In order to solve this I would create the following tables:

1. account (id, name, address, login, password, etc.)
2. supplier (id, account, ...)
3. client
4. etc.

Now you create a relation between supplier and account and client and account. In oder to allow a company to have multiple logins I create child-accounts for a company account. In order to do this you could have a field called `parent` and create a relation to another account and maybe a field called `type` where you want to define if it is a user account or company account.

You can bind contact information to the company account and let the child-accounts use these information. By using this it's also way easier to track which user is doing what. Depending on your clients/suppliers and where you're located this can be also necessary in order to comply with corporate compliance.

By defining differnt account types you can also define what these accounts can do (permission handling based on their type in addition to their groups etc.). For example a user account may change the address but a company account may only do this after approval.

I wouldn't bind user accounts to suppliers but instead bind it to another company/organisation account (as I already described) which then get's referenced by the supplier table. You can now basically bind every information to one account instead of multiple but still providing these information the the child-accounts (if needed and practicable). This has way more benefits like easily beeing able to keep track of account relations etc. You could now also bind one account to multiple company accounts which is not entirely uncommon if someone is working for a company that has a sister company.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I like having a column that determines privilege level, but I don't like having parents and children in the same table, isn't that what you're suggesting?